# Logical content of Gauss's Lemma (arithmetic)

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

In the context where $a$, $b$, $c$ are integers we have $(a \mid bc, a\land b = 1) \Rightarrow a\mid c$. This result is called *Gauss's Lemma* in French Highschool.
It is well known that (Steve Awodey, *Category Theory*) the divisibility relation $a \mid b$ can be interpreted as the logical implication $a \to b$. In this setting, the gcd $a \land b$ becomes the associated conjunction $a$ AND $b$ with the universal property : $(c \to a, c \to b) \vdash c \to a \land b$. Dually, the lcm $a \lor b$ is interpreted as the disjunction.

My question : in this setting, how would you read Gauss's Lemma given above ?

Bricks for the answer :

1. $\forall a, 1 \mid a$ reminds me of the *ex falso quod libet* (explosion principle) also reading $\bot \to P$ (from false  deduce anything) ;
2. $a \land b = 1$ would thus be read NOT($a$ AND $b$) ?
3. if $d = b \cdot c$, $b$ becomes a proof that $c \mid d$.

From there on, I'm not yet able to conclude anything worthy, but I'm sure there's something….

Comment: If the statement of the lemma was weakened to use $\lcm(b,c)$ in place of $bc$, you could read it as $a\to b\lor c,\neg(a\land b)\vdash a\to c$.

Comment: your interpretation of the relaxed Gauss' lemma makes sense! It remains to understand the interpretation of the strong version with $b \lor c$ replaced by $bc$

Comment: Gauss's Lemma was certainly known to Euclid. See Proposition 30 of Book VII of the Elements, and read "Outline of the proof" here: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII30.html

Comment: Euclid's lemma assumes $a$ prime and $a | bc$ and yields  $a | b$ OR $a | c$

Comment: *Semi proof* of Gauss' Lemma (logical interpretation) : we prove $a \to c$ under the assumptions  $a \to bc$ and NOT($a$ AND $b$). If De Morgan's law holds, the last assumption can be rewritten as NOT $a$ OR NOT $b$. But to prove $a \to c$, we assume $a$. The second assumption then yields NOT $b$ also written $b \to 1$ or $b|1$. Now comes the "semi" side of the proof. 
From $b | 1$ we  get $bc | c$ (obvious arithmetically speaking, less obvious to me on the logical side).
We now have $a$, $a\to bc$, $bc \to c$, hence $c$. QED

Comment: @smed Yes, but if you read his proof, you will see that he proves Gauss's Lemma on the way. Read "Outline of the proof" on the linked page from "$d$ is relatively prime to $a$".

Comment: For the record, let me spell out Euclid's proof of Gauss's Lemma. Assume that $a\mid bc$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then $bc=ad$, and hence $a/b=c/d$. The fraction $a/b$ is in lowest terms by Proposition VII.21, hence $a\mid c$ by Proposition VII.20.

Comment: Since you [specify](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462317/logical-content-of-gausss-lemma-arithmetic#comment1199570_462317) that you are interested in the statement with $b c$ instead of $\operatorname{lcm}(b, c)$, without worrying about the full statement yet, is the machinery you've set up even enough to define multiplication ‘logically’?

Comment: For an interpretation of multiplication, see the third *brick for the answer* in the original message.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1199608), right, that is an *interpretation* of multiplication, but it seems to suggest at best a metalogical *definition* of multiplication ("$b c$ is that integer $d$ of which $c$ is a proof that $b$ divides $d$").  What I mean by "logical definition" is a proposition $P(b, c, d)$ such that, for each pair $(b, c)$, the unique value of $d$ making $P(b, c, d)$ true is $d = b c$ (so, for example, "$\forall e.\text{$(\text{$e \mid b$ and $e \mid c$})$ implies $(e \mid d)$}$" would be such a proposition $Q(b, c, d)$ defining $\gcd(b, c)$).

Comment: I've been working on how to interpret the multiplication. In a categorical setting, I came to interpret the multiplication $bc$ as the pushout of the diagram $b \leftarrow 1 \rightarrow c$. The whole picture is here <img src="https://imgur.com/a3yG5F0">

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462317/logical-content-of-gausss-lemma-arithmetic#comment1199893_462317), I don't understand—I would think, and your diagram seems to support, that the pushout is actually $\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
@. b \\
@. @VVV \\
c @>>> b \vee c.
\end{CD}$

Comment: @LSpice That's the pushout over $b \wedge c$. The pushout over the initial object, $1$, is the coproduct $b \coprod c$ which the OP suggests interpreting as bc.

Comment: But bc simply isn't the coproduct, if the category is the preorder defined by divisibility. The coproduct is the lcm.

Comment: Nobody has asked yet what in the world it means to say that divisibility “can be interpreted as” logical implication. Certainly there is a divisibility partial order and lcm and gcd can be constructed as sup and inf in that order, but what else is there to say about this supposed interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that by a 'logical interpretation' we mean that we assign logical connectives and require that at least the introduction and elimination rules of propositional logic/natural deduction involving these connectives hold true under this assignation. One doesn't have so many connectives to choose from, and divisibility has already been assigned to implication, whilst gcd has already been assigned to conjunction. Multiplication has to be assigned to something, and the only possibility that is not obviously wrong is disjunction. Disjunction introduction does hold under this interpretation: $p \mid pq$ and $q \mid pq$. Disjunction elimination does not quite, however: it would say that, for any $s$, we have that $s \mid pq$ and $p \mid r$ and $q \mid r$ implies $s \mid r$, which is not necessarily true (it *is* true if lcm is used instead).

However, one can simply either settle for a slight weakening of the elimination rule, or change one of the other assignations. For example, if one adds the hypothesis 'given $r \vee r$, we infer $r$' (which would correspond here to: for any $s$, if $s \mid r^{2}$, then $s \mid r$, which holds if and only if $r$ is prime or $1$) to the statement of disjunction elimination, then it *does* hold. Or if one does not assign divisibility to implication but rather 'divisibility where the divisor is square-free', then disjunction elimination in its original form does hold.

However one does it, the idea is that with multiplication interpreted as disjunction or some weakened form of it, Gauss's lemma can be interpreted as Emil suggested in the comments: from $a \rightarrow b \vee c$ and $\neg(a \wedge b)$, we infer that $a \rightarrow c$, which of course does hold in classical propositional logic. In particular, one assigns equality with $1$ to the connective $\neg$ in one's logical intepretation, and one can check that the introduction and elimination rules for negation do hold under this interpretation.

(The following was added later: the 'final paragraph' in my comment below is the paragraph above.)

If one wishes to think category-theoretically, divisibility by a square-free natural number does not quite define a preorder, as one does not have identities, but one can just chuck the latter in (or tweak to 'divisibility by a square-free natural number or by itself'). In this preorder/semi-preorder, one still has finite products given by gcd. One does not quite have coproducts, but I would argue that these are not the right thing to ask for here. The right thing as I see it, as in what I called disjunction elimination above, is to require the following universal property: given $p$ and $q$, there is a $u$ and arrows $p \rightarrow u$ and $q \rightarrow u$ such that for any $r$, $p \rightarrow r$, $q \rightarrow r$, and $s \rightarrow u$, there is an $s \rightarrow r$ (uniqueness being tautologous in a preorder/semi-preorder). Something like this may have been what the original poster was trying to express in the comment. As above, an alternative to working with square-free numbers is tweaking what elimination means, in which case the universal property would become: given $p$ and $q$, there is a $u$ and arrows $p \rightarrow u$ and $q \rightarrow u$ such that for any $r$, $p \rightarrow r$, $q \rightarrow r$, and $r \circ r \rightarrow r$, there is a $u \rightarrow r$ factoring through $r \circ r$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this answers "how would you read Gauss's  Lemma given above?"?

Comment: Added in the final paragraph now.